# Can you use EXISTS with OR in SQL?

Tags: sql, nested, exists

Ok so the question states that I have to list all restaurants that have been reviewed by “Daniel Johnston” or have both a type “Italian” and at least one rating score of at least 4.

I've been trying this query:

```
SELECT name
FROM RESTAURANT
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT rest_id
    FROM RESTAURANT, RATES
    WHERE RESTAURANT.rest_id=RATES.rest_id AND RESTAURANT.type = 'Italian' AND RATES.score>=4)
OR rest_id IN
    (SELECT rest_id
    FROM REVIEWS, USER
    WHERE USER.user_id=REVIEWS.user_id AND USER.fname = 'Daniel' AND USER.sname = 'Johnston');
```

but it keeps returning errors. I've run the different parts separately and they are ok. So I'm wondering if I can't use EXISTS and OR, and if I can't, what would be a better way?

My logic is that I want the name of the restaurant if it's Italian and has at least one review score of over 4, so EXISTS is suitable for that, and using two EXISTS doesn't seem to make any difference which is why I revert back to the normal nested query for the second part. I've messed around a lot and I cannot seem to figure out where I am wrong, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We might find it helpful to see the errors you're getting. Also, which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Why can't you just use `where rest_id IN(...)` two times?

Answer (score 1):

Subqueries seldom give the best performance, probably faster with a straight forward JOIN; it also makes the naming easier with fewer conflicting names (rest_id conflicts in a non obvious way with one of the inner queries in your example)

```
SELECT name
FROM RESTAURANT
LEFT JOIN RATES
  ON RESTAURANT.rest_id = RATES.rest_id
LEFT JOIN REVIEWS
  ON RESTAURANT.rest_id = REVIEWS.rest_id
LEFT JOIN [USER]
  ON REVIEWS.user_id = [USER].user_id
WHERE RESTAURANT.type = 'Italian' AND RATES.score>=4
   OR [USER].fname = 'Daniel' AND [USER].sname = 'Johnston';
```

Simple demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11946/1).

As a more to the point response to your question, yes, you can definitely use EXISTS with OR, you just have to keep your names straight between the main query and the subqueries and the query you have should work fine too.

Comment: Classic error: the results now has more rows and further investigation shows the result contains duplicate rows, we no longer have relational data. Add the `DISTINCT` keyword and all the performance benefits go out the window (in a similarly sweeping statement about all SQL products :)

Comment: @onedaywhen Oops, yes, I lost the DISTINCT somewhere between the head and the keyboard apparently. What database are you using? It still seems to give a ~3 times performance benefit in TSQL compared to the subselects (of course I may not have the same amounts of data)

Comment: I'm using the `Airplanes` database ;)

Comment: @onedaywhen Heh, I'm having a bad day apparently ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name 
FROM RESTAURANT 
WHERE rest_id IN (SELECT rest_id 
                  FROM RESTAURANT, RATES 
                  WHERE RESTAURANT.rest_id=RATES.rest_id 
                  AND RESTAURANT.type = 'Italian' 
                  AND RATES.score>=4) 
OR rest_id IN (SELECT rest_id 
               FROM REVIEWS, USER 
               WHERE USER.user_id=REVIEWS.user_id 
               AND USER.fname = 'Daniel' 
               AND USER.sname = 'Johnston');
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only see one thing wrong with your existing query, and that is that in this subquery:

```
SELECT rest_id
    FROM RESTAURANT, RATES
    WHERE RESTAURANT.rest_id=RATES.rest_id AND RESTAURANT.type = 'Italian' AND RATES.score>=4
```

...you would need to specify *which* rest_id you wanted to retrieve, i.e.

```
SELECT RESTAURANT.rest_id
    FROM RESTAURANT, RATES
    WHERE RESTAURANT.rest_id=RATES.rest_id AND RESTAURANT.type = 'Italian' AND RATES.score>=4
```

Having said that, if you've run that query separately and it's worked, as you say, I can't quite figure out why, unless you're using an RDBMS I'm not familiar with. There's generally no reason why you can't mix EXISTS with IN using an OR. Certainly, with my edit, the query should work with common language implementations like MySQL or Trasact-SQL.

Comment: I was using openoffice Base, and then I used Access and my query ran fine. Thanks for the answers though :)

Comment: Ah, yes. OpenOffice Base is, from what I remember of my experiences, a teensy bit odd in a fair few places. But then my experiences are quite dated...